# Use sites.php to point https and http to diffent sites

Tags: multi-sites

I've got several Drupal sites on different domains running on the same code using sites.php.

What I want to do is point the same domain to different sites depending on whether it's accessed via http or https.

For example, in sites.php
$sites['http://www.example.com']='site1';
$sites['https://www.example.com']='site2';

However, the above doesn't work. It looks like you can't specify protocol in sites.php.

Thanks,

Robin

Answer (score 2):

Please read through the default `example.sites.php` file again. A `protocol` is the same thing as a `port` (they have a 1-to-1 relationship when we talk about a webserver).

`http` is implied by default in the rule describing `www.example.com`. `http` is also implied to be Port 80, otherwise known as `:80` in a URI-scheme.

Your format is completely wrong for any subsite defined in `$sites`. From the documentation it would be:

```
$sites['www.example.com']='site1';   // Normal HTTP www.foo.com
$sites['443.www.example.com']='site2';  // SSL version (port 443 by default for www.foo.com)
```